# IIS compression doesnt open excel file properly.Shows message that file cannot be accessed or corrupted,located on a server that is not responding

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, sql-server-2008

we have used IIS 7 compression on asp.net application .The application downloads a excel file and opens it properly when compression is not applied.When compression is applied the excel file downloads but doesn't open properly. It shows a message that the file cannot be accessed.The file may be corrupted,located on a server that is not responding or read-only.
Please suggest what is going wrong.Why is the file opening with error.What resolution can be applied.Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the file actually download? if so always worth opening it up in notepad to see if it actually contains a textual error written by the server after the mime/content-type headers were set

Comment: Is this an Excel 201o document?

Comment: Yes. the file downloads but does'nt open properly.

Comment: Hi David, its Excel 2003 document. it has .xls format.

Answer (score 0):

Is the downloaded file perhaps still gzipped on the drive, but with a .xls extension?  I'm guessing this shouldn't happen, but would be my first guess.  You can probably just check the file size and compare it to the original as a quick check.

Also, does this happen with all browsers, or just a specific one?

Comment: Daniel,The file gets downloads and opens correctly when we dont apply iis compression.The problem is when we apply iis compression that the file throws some message and when i click ok on that message.the file opens with one or two rows of data with header row.I checked the downloaded file size seems to be 300kb which is fine.

Comment: This is pretty strange, if I had to hazard another guess, I would say that the transmission is getting interrupted halfway through.  It's difficult to comment without further information though.  I would try to compare the two files (the "uncompressed" one and the one that was served using compression), and try to take it from there.  You might pick up some useful info.  Another thing to consider is that something might be interrupting the transmission on purpose, such as an in-between firewall which thinks you are transmitting a virus (I've had this happen before).

Comment: Hi @Daniel , I see the original file size and downloaded file size to be same. What could be the reason that the file gets corrupted and does'nt open properly.

Comment: I guess the file sizes are the same because the size of the file is known at the time the download is started, and the browser creates a file of the correct size upfront.  I'm sure there is a difference in the contents however, otherwise you wouldn't have a problem.  My suggestion was that you inspect / compare the files using a hex editor to see where exactly the problem starts.  My guess is that at a certain point in the file, the transmission is interrupted for some reason.  It's difficult to guess what the problem is exactly, it's quite unusual.

Comment: I checked the file contents, they are same.The excel sheets have lost their macros(buttons and colors and formats).My only worry is it all works fine when u dont apply http compression.When http compression is enabled the file downloads but doesnt open properly.it will lose its macros.can we think on this point as there is no firewall restrictions as such.

Comment: The macros have been lost after download.

Comment: Can you confirm that the file contents are absolutely identical?  Please check this using an MD5 hash generator such as [this one](http://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/content/md5-hash).  If they are identical, then the difference must be with how the browser interprets what it is receiving, which is quite possible.  Please check the hashes first and then we can continue.

Comment: Yes the file contents are identical.Actually the downloaded file shows the message that:"Damage to the file was so extensive that repairs  were not possible.Excel attempted to recover your formulas and values,but some data may have been lost or corrupted."Belive me the files are identical in data.And the downloaded file has lost the formulas, formatting etc.May be now your doubts are very clear.

Comment: Well, I can't really help you much more; I see two possibilities:  1.  The file is actually getting corrupted during the download.  2.  The way in which Excel is instructed to open the file by the browser is different.  According to the error you are getting, it seems to be #1.  Despite your comment that the data is the same, this doesn't seem to be the case.  Unfortunately there isn't much else I can offer to help.